# Insert Custom Post Type data from the front-end by a user

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

We created a custom post type "items" and it is showing in the admin. Now, we want users to insert an item from the front-end. This will be linked to a menu item called "My Account" so a user can see all his inserted items and can add new item by clicking a link "Add New Item".

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know the community prefers coded answers rather than a plug-in alternative.  Especially since alot of frontend dedicated plug-ins are bloated or fail to accomplish most users desires.

But I would recommend a combination of [Gravity forms](https://www.gravityhelp.com/), which is well supported and documented,  this will give you or your client easily manageable front facing forms which can submit to a custom post type and/or custom fields.

[Gravity sticky List](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-sticky-list/) -  which will extend Gravity forms and allow front-end editing and/or display of already submitted forms/posts.

Answer (score 0):

I did something recently like that.

Try this plugin WP User Frontend (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/)

The free version will let you do what you need.

Comment: Its  a complete plugin, we need the proper steps, how we proceed further.

Comment: the install instructions have all the steps you need: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/installation/

More details here:
http://docs.wedevs.com/wp-user-frontend-pro/#usage
these are for the pro version, but there is overlap with the free version

Answer (score 0):

> Try This Custom Code For Create Post From Front End
>
> Insert Data in Custom Post From Front End

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "product") {

    $title     = $_POST['title'];
    $post_type = 'product';
    //the array of arguements to be inserted with wp_insert_post
    $front_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',          
    'post_type'     => $post_type 
    );

    //insert the the post into database by passing $new_post to wp_insert_post
    //store our post ID in a variable $pid
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($front_post);
    //we now use $pid (post id) to help add out post meta data
    update_post_meta($post_id, "short_description", @$_POST["short_description"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "price", @$_POST["price"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "length", @$_POST["length"]);
```

> HTML Code Here

```
<form method="POST">
<label>Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='title'>
        <label>Product Description</label>
        <textarea value="" rows="3" class="input-xlarge" name='short_description'>
        </textarea>
 <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='price'>
        <label>Dimensions (in):</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" name='length' placeholder="Length">
  <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="product" />
 </from>
```